# Is it possible to deploy SSAS Tabular Models on a schedule(handle automatically) rather than manually?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2012, deployment, ssas, tabular

Question details: My boss has asked me to do a little digging on a way to automatically deploy Tabular models from Visual Studios to the Production Database using some sort of scheduling. I'm trying to find if this can be done with external software or if there are built in ways to accomplish this task.

Description of current process: Edit Tabular Model in Visual Studios which is deployed to a test database. Once verified that the model is ready for production it is then merged with the production version of the model and manually deployed to the Production Database.  <----This is the part that I want to set on a schedule, so that I could do something such as configure a couple test models to be deployed automatically, at lets say 6:00a.m, to some Database Server Address

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done.  The best way is if your visual studio workspace server is set to an actual development server, and not your local PC.

Right click "Databases" under the SSAS server, and click "synchronize".  Select the options for source (the source database should be your workspace database (which will have a really long name with lots of letters), and your production database info.  At the end of this menu process, select to view the script in a new query window.  Copy the synchronization script into a SQL Server Agent job, and schedule that job for the time that you want to run it.